# Raphael paper zoom animation

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, zooming, raphael

I managed to do some hack in order to zoom raphael paper, as setviewbox wasn't working for me, here is the function I wrote:

```
function setCTM(element, matrix) {
    var s = "matrix(" + matrix.a + "," + matrix.b + "," + matrix.c + "," + matrix.d + "," + matrix.e + "," + matrix.f + ")";

    element.setAttribute("transform", s);
}

Raphael.fn.zoomAndMove = function(coordx,coordy,zoom) {

    var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

    var z = zoom;

    var g = document.getElementById("viewport1");
    var p = svg.createSVGPoint();

    p.x = coordx; 
    p.y = coordy;

    p = p.matrixTransform(g.getCTM().inverse());

    var k = svg.createSVGMatrix().scale(z).translate(-p.x, -p.y);
    setCTM(g, g.getCTM().multiply(k));
}
```

where the viewport1 element was defined as :

```
var gelem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
gelem.id = 'viewport1';

paper.canvas.appendChild(gelem);
paper.canvas = gelem;
```

Then I can call: `paper.zoomAndMove(minx,miny,zoomRatio);`

Is it possible to transform the function to make it zoom smoothly?

Comment: Please provide a basic example, to see how the zooming currently performs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hardwickj/9zu4U/1177/) for utilizing jQuery and Raphael's setViewBox which does both zooming and panning smoothly. We use the exact same functionality in a much more complicated and larger context and it works perfect and remains smooth even with a large number of items drawn on screen.

Basically, don't try and re-invent the wheel. I know this may not be the answer you are looking for, but it's almost certainly your best option.

EDIT:
I've fixed the attached fiddle (it was broken due to changes JSFiddle made to the site) but apparently SO won't let me save JSFiddle links without including some code, so...

```
console.log("hello world!");
```

Comment: you have not included rapheal as dependency in the fiddle. Just mentioned :). Here is [**an update**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zu4U/1042/).

Comment: Thanks @mithunsatheesh! I fixed my fiddle and updated the link. Apparently JSFiddle made some changes that broke the original fiddle. It's now working again.

Answer (score 14):

For anybody (like me) who wanted to have the zooming & panning smoothly animated have a look here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/raphaeljs/7eA9xq4enDo

this snipped helped me to automate and animate zooming and panning to a specific point on the canvas. (Props to [Will Morgan](https://plus.google.com/100959992193914915762))

```
Raphael.fn.animateViewBox = function(currentViewBox, viewX, viewY, width, height, duration, callback) {

    duration = duration || 250;

    var originals = currentViewBox, //current viewBox Data from where the animation should start
        differences = {
                x: viewX - originals.x,
                y: viewY - originals.y,
                width: width - originals.width,
                height: height - originals.height
        },
        delay = 13,
        stepsNum = Math.ceil(duration / delay),
        stepped = {
                x: differences.x / stepsNum,
                y: differences.y / stepsNum,
                width: differences.width / stepsNum,
                height: differences.height / stepsNum
        }, i,
        canvas = this;

    /**
     * Using a lambda to protect a variable with its own scope.
     * Otherwise, the variable would be incremented inside the loop, but its
     * final value would be read at run time in the future.
     */
    function timerFn(iterator) {
            return function() {
                    canvas.setViewBox(
                            originals.x + (stepped.x * iterator),
                            originals.y + (stepped.y * iterator),
                            originals.width + (stepped.width * iterator),
                            originals.height + (stepped.height * iterator)
                    );
                    // Run the callback as soon as possible, in sync with the last step
                    if(iterator == stepsNum && callback) {
                            callback(viewX, viewY, width, height);
                    }
            }
    }

    // Schedule each animation step in to the future
    // Todo: use some nice easing
    for(i = 1; i <= stepsNum; ++i) {
            setTimeout(timerFn(i), i * delay);
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I am looking for, my only question is how do I generate the `currentViewBox` parameter? Thanks

Comment: hope this helps?`var currentViewBox = {  
x: me.currPos.x,
y: me.currPos.y,
width: paper.width * (1 - (me.currZoom * settings.zoomStep)),
height: paper.height * (1 - (me.currZoom * settings.zoomStep))
};`

Comment: Can this be used for zooming linecharts ? From http://g.raphaeljs.com/ ?An example/Jsfiddle will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Minor mod to patrics' answer to get rid of "currentViewBox"... this works with Raphael 2.1.0:

```
Raphael.fn.animateViewBox = function(viewX, viewY, width, height, duration, callback) {

    duration = duration || 250;

    //current viewBox Data from where the animation should start
    var originals = {
            x: this._viewBox[0], 
            y: this._viewBox[1], 
            width: this._viewBox[2], 
            height: this._viewBox[3]
    }, 
    differences = {
            x: viewX - originals.x,
            y: viewY - originals.y,
            width: width - originals.width,
            height: height - originals.height
    },
    delay = 13,
    stepsNum = Math.ceil(duration / delay),
    stepped = {
            x: differences.x / stepsNum,
            y: differences.y / stepsNum,
            width: differences.width / stepsNum,
            height: differences.height / stepsNum
    }, i,
    canvas = this;

    /**
     * Using a lambda to protect a variable with its own scope.
     * Otherwise, the variable would be incremented inside the loop, but its
     * final value would be read at run time in the future.
     */
    function timerFn(iterator) {
        return function() {
                canvas.setViewBox(
                        originals.x + (stepped.x * iterator),
                        originals.y + (stepped.y * iterator),
                        originals.width + (stepped.width * iterator),
                        originals.height + (stepped.height * iterator),
                        true
                );
                // Run the callback as soon as possible, in sync with the last step
                if(iterator == stepsNum && callback) {
                        callback(viewX, viewY, width, height);
                }
        }
    }

    // Schedule each animation step in to the future
    // Todo: use some nice easing
    for(i = 1; i <= stepsNum; ++i) {
        setTimeout(timerFn(i), i * delay);
    }
}
```

*Sry if it's bad etiquette to post a mod.  Feel free to merge it in patrics' version, but then the comments don't make sense.*

Answer (score 2):

Similar to above, but with differences:

- Doesn't depend on internals (which have since changed)
- Doesn't require any global set up (it is handled for you)
- Uses requestAnimationFrame, resulting in much smoother animations (but **does not work in IE9 or below**)
- Uses [Raphael's easing functions](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Raphael.easing_formulas) (`linear`, `easeIn`, `easeOut`, `easeInOut`, `backIn`, `backOut`, `elastic`, `bounce`)

Since this is a complete rewrite I didn't modify the above.

```
 Raphael.fn.animateViewBox = function(viewX, viewY, width, height, duration, callback, easing) {
    var start = window.performance.now(),
      canvas = this;

    easing = Raphael.easing_formulas[ easing || 'linear' ];
    duration = duration === undefined ? 250 : duration;

    if (canvas.currentViewBox == undefined) {
        canvas.currentViewBox = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: this._viewBox ? this._viewBox[2] : canvas.width,
            height: this._viewBox ? this._viewBox[3] : canvas.height 
        }
    }

    function step(timestamp) {
        var progress = timestamp - start;
        var progressFraction = progress/duration;

        if (progressFraction > 1) {
            progressFraction = 1;
        }

        var easedProgress = easing( progressFraction );
        var newViewBox = {
            x: canvas.currentViewBox.x + (viewX - canvas.currentViewBox.x) * easedProgress,
            y: canvas.currentViewBox.y + (viewY - canvas.currentViewBox.y) * easedProgress,
            width: canvas.currentViewBox.width + (width - canvas.currentViewBox.width) * easedProgress,
            height: canvas.currentViewBox.height + (height - canvas.currentViewBox.height) * easedProgress
        };
        canvas.setViewBox(newViewBox.x, newViewBox.y, newViewBox.width, newViewBox.height, false);

        if (progressFraction < 1) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            canvas.currentViewBox = newViewBox;
            if (callback) {
                callback(newViewBox.x, newViewBox.y, newViewBox.width, newViewBox.height);
            }
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

Comment: +1 This has the smoothest animations of any on this page for me. The initial version fell over with a heap of `NaN`s if your canvas is set to a % width or height (e.g. `'100%'`). I've made an edit that prevents this if `this._viewBox` is available (which it should be)